# Relationship between ResolveAsk.com and StackExchange

Tags: discussion

Whilst doing some internet research for a question, I stumbled upon [ResolveAsk](https://www.resolveask.com/).  It seems that all the questions asked in all StackExchange sites are mirrored onto the site.  Interestingly, looking at the site list, they don't have CognitiveSciences updated to Psychology&Neuroscience (the current name) and so I was wondering if this is part of StackExchange or is ResolveAsk stealing our work?

Comment: All Stack Exchange content is licensed under CC-BY-SA, so they are free to republish iff they provide proper attribution (if not, contact SE support).

Comment: Thanks @amon.  I have seen that in the original question and just this minute reported it through SE support as they are not providing proper attributions.